# Smallest difference pair of values between two list

Tags: python-3.x

I have two `list`s of integers. I need to find one element from each list, which the absolute difference is minimal.

Execution time is 1 second and my code exceeds the allowed time. How do I optimize it?

```
m = int(input())   #number of elements in list1
list1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
z = int(input())    #number of elements in list2
list2 = list(map(int, input().split()))
minDiference = abs(list1[0] - list2[0])
for i in range (m):
    for j in range(z):
        diference = abs(list1[i] - list2[j])
        if difference < mindifference:
            mindifference = difference
print(mindifference)
```

Comment: your approach can be improved slightly by using a list comprehension `min_abs_dif = abs(min([x-y for x in l1 for y in l2], key=abs))` - however it is much more efficient to sort the lists first and then do a comparison of the elements as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-difference-pair-values-two-unsorted-arrays/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current complexity is `O(m*z)`, you could reduce it to `O(max(m*log(m), z*log(z))` By sorting the lists !

```
l1 = sorted(list1)
l2 = sorted(list2)

i = j = 0

minimum = float('inf')

while i < m and j < z:
    diff = l1[i] - l2[j]
    minimum = min(minimum, abs(diff))
    if diff < 0: # Means the value of the current position is lower than the l2's, move the l1's pointer
        i += 1
    elif diff > 0: # Quite similar
        j += 1
    else:
        break

print(minimum)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `numpy` and `itertools` you could do:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

x=list(itertools.product(list1,list2))
y=x[np.array(list(map(lambda s: abs(sum(s)), x))).argmin()]
print(y)
```

Comment: The algorithmic complexity remains the same :/

Comment: Yup, I would call it more technology-boost, than algorithmic boost (as in fact it's simple brute-force approach). Question is, which one was meant by OP to be tackled here.